# How can undefined be a function?

Tags: javascript, typeerror

Can you explain how does work this code block?

```js
(function() { function undefined(){}; undefined() })()
```

Comment: It's just an Immediate Invoked Function Expression (IIFE) that defines a function called `undefined` and invokes it.

Comment: you have a function *named* `undefined` and you are executing it

Answer (score 0):

`undefined` is not a keyword, it is just an identifier.

In the global scope, `undefined` is read only.

In the scope of the IIFE you have, you can create a new `undefined` variable that masks the global one.

---

Don't do that. It confuses people trying to maintain the code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In the same code null doesn't act like undefined and null also is not a keyword either, am I wrong?

Comment: Yes. [See MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar) which says: Additionally, the literals null, true, and false cannot be used as identifiers in ECMAScript.

Answer (score 0):

```js
(function() {
  function undefined() {
    alert('d')
  };
  undefined()

  alert(undefined)
})()

alert(undefined)
```

This works because you are naming the function `undefined` inside a function. This means, inside the function's local scope, `undefined` = the function. As you can see if you run the code snippet, outside the function's scope, `undefined` = undefined once again.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How does provide JavaScript to deny to define variable named undefined in global execution context(global scope)? How can not to deny in activation object(function scope)

Comment: @ikarus I'm sorry, I don't understand the question.